# How to get the ref of a child component inside parent component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a parent component and a child component as following.

**Parent component:**

```
constructor(){
    this.refs = React.createRef();
}

setRef(ref) {
    console.log(ref)
}

handleChange(e) {
    console.log(e)
}

render() {
    return(
        <ChildComponent ref={this.setRef} handleChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
    )
}
```

**Child Component:**

```
render() {
    return(
        <input type="text" ref={this.props.ref} onChange={this.props.handleChange.bind(this)} > </input>
    )
}
```

What changes should I do to get the `ref` value inside the `handleChange()` function in parent component? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set the refs value to one variable and access it in the handleChange() function

Comment: You mean by creating a global variable?

Comment: not global variable in constructor we can take one object and assigns the refs values to it and in  handleChange() you can use that values thought the obj value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I´m reading correctly you want to access the `input` element from the parent component?

You have to use another name for your prop as `ref` is a keyword prop which will automatically assign the component the given variable.

```
<ChildComponent inputRef={this.setRef} handleChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>

class ChildComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <input type="text" ref={this.props.inputRef} onChange= {this.props.handleChange.bind(this)} > </input>
        );
    }
}
```

Based on how you want to access the ref you can either set `this.refs` directly to the prop or set it inside your `setRef` function.

```
// either `this.refs` and then usable through `this.refs.current`
<ChildComponent inputRef={this.refs} {...} />

// or `this.setRef` and assign it yourself
setRef = (ref) => {this.refs = ref;}
```

Comment: Yes. But how can I read this `ref` inside `handleChange()` function in the parent component?

Comment: By just using `this.refs` if you are using your `setRef` function or `this.refs.current` if it is directly used as the `inputRef` prop.

Comment: I added `this.refs = React.createRef()` inside the parent constructor. But when i tried assigning the `refs` to `this.refs` I'm getting error `Cannot set property 'refs' of undefined`

Comment: You might also need to use `this.setRef = this.setRef.bind(this)` in constructor or use arrow-notation as seen in my answer above.

Comment: Cool! Thanks Rallen

Answer (score 2):

`ref`(as well as `key` btw) is very special prop. It is not accessible in child by `this.props.ref`.

Shortest way is to use different prop to pass `ref` forward and backward:

```
class Parent ...
    render() {
    ...
        <Child inputRef={this.inputRef} />

class Child 
...
    render() {
        <input ref={this.props.inputRef} ...
```

It's most flexible since you may access different `ref` inside you child component(e.g. `inputRef` + `scrollableContainerRef` + `popupRef`)

But in some cases you want to compose new component for existing code base. Say `<input>`'s replacement. Sure, in this case you would avoid changing all `<input ref={...} />` onto `<MyInput refProp={...}>`.

Here you may use [`React.forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html). It feels the best with functional components like

```
export Child = React.forwardRef((props, forwardedRef) => {
    ...
    return ...
        <input ref={forwardedRef} />
})
```

But for class-based component you would rather use `ref-prop` with different name:

```
class Child
...
    render()
        return
        ...
        <input ref={this.props.forwardedRefName} />

export ChildWithForwardRef = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <Child forwardedRefName={ref} {...props} />)
```

PS since you will consume what `forwardRef` returns rather initial component(`Child`) you may want to specify `displayName` for it. This way you may be able find it later say with enzyme's `find()` or easy recognize element in browser's React DevTools

Answer (score 0):

`ref` work only on native dom element, to make ref work on user defined Component, you need this:

https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html